# how to add more colums in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb.SERIAL_NUM, tb.REVISION_NUM, tb.JOB_NUM, tb.JOB_TOTAL, tb.TEST_PROC, tb.BOX_NUM, tb.TEST_BENCH, tb.OPERATOR, tb.SW_REVISION, tb.TEST_DATE, tb.VISUAL_INSP, tb.TEST, tb.STATUS FROM tb
WHERE tb.SERIAL_NUM>=%s  
AND tb.SERIAL_NUM <=%s 
AND tb.TEST = 'Pass' GROUP BY  tb.SERIAL_NUM
```

It's working fine but in my table there are 200 more columns I would like to add to this query, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb.SERIAL_NUM, tb.REVISION_NUM, tb.JOB_NUM, tb.JOB_TOTAL, tb.TEST_PROC, tb.BOX_NUM, tb.TEST_BENCH, tb.OPERATOR, tb.SW_REVISION, tb.TEST_DATE, tb.VISUAL_INSP, tb.TEST, tb.STATUS, column15.....,column215 FROM tb
WHERE tb.SERIAL_NUM>=%s  AND tb.SERIAL_NUM <=%s AND tb.TEST = 'Pass' GROUP BY  tb.SERIAL_NUM
```

**Is there a simple way to add those column in the query ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use select * like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <table> WHERE <whereClause>
```

Comment: @BayoAlen distinct should work with *. edited the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to get all the fields. then copy and paste into your query...  schema/system tables are indeed powerful.

```
SELECT Group_concat(COLUMN_NAME Separator ', ') as allTableFields
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tb'
Group By table_name
```

What this does (or should do) is get a list of all the fields from the columns in the database for table tb.  it then groups them together with a comma then space as separators.  So the results should be something like

field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6... field215